# Remove all special characters from a string not including non-latin characters

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to remove all the special characters from a string except numbers and normal a-z characters.

I am doing it like this:

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", "");
```

The problem with this way is that it will also remove all non-latin characters like è, é, ê, ë and many others.

By non-special characters (the ones I want to keep) I mean all the numbers and all the alphabetical characters for all the languages or at least as many as possible.

How do I only remove the special characters?

Comment: Maybe you should define what special characters are. Which set is bigger?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Special characters are all characters except numerical and alphabetical in all languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `\p{L}` for all letters and `\p{N}` for all numbers:

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N} ]+", "");
```

Comment: +1 although you don't need a quantifier and you can use `\\P` instead of a class negation.

Comment: Tried `[\\P{L}\\P{N} ]+` and it ate everything :|

Comment: because the second term cancels the first one. You'd have to replace twice. Unfortunately the `Alnum` posix doesn't work with Unicode...

Answer (score 1):

I know you said regex, *but if guava is an option*:

```
CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.retainFrom("èêAAAGRt123")
```